# How to use $state.go on ng-submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a search form on a results page for small search app built using AngularJS and Elasticsearch. Just started using UI-Router from ngRoute and need to figure out how to use $state.go() on my ng-submit button for the search form to return results on the results page.

UI Router config

```
$stateProvider
.state('search', {
  url: '/',
  views: {
    '': {templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'},//parent view
    'navbar@search': {templateUrl: 'templates/navbar.html', controller: 'TypeaheadCtrl'},
    'searchDisplay@search': {templateUrl: 'templates/results.html', controller: 'TypeaheadCtrl'},
    'pagination@search': {templateUrl: 'templates/pagination.html', controller: 'TypeaheadCtrl'}
  }
})
```

Search form

```
<form ng-submit="search()" class="navbar-form" id="global-search" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="q" ng-model="searchTerms" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Search" id="search-input" uib-typeahead="query for query in getSuggestions($viewValue)" typeahead-on-select="search($item)" autofocus>
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

My ng-submit currently calls search() which looks like this after I added $state.go()

```
$scope.search = function() {
resetResults();
$scope.filters.selectedFilters = [];

var searchTerms = $scope.searchTerms;

if (searchTerms) {
  $scope.results.searchTerms = searchTerms;
} else {
  return;
}

$state.go('/search', {term: $scope.searchTerms});

getResults();//uses service to get results data from search server
```

};

This results in this error: Error: Could not resolve '/search' from state 'search'
    at Object.y.transitionTo

Have no idea what to do with that, still getting my head around UI-Router. 
Just trying to figure out the best method to use for ng-submit to send search query. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall write state name in `state.go` instead of url:

```
$state.go('search', {term: $scope.searchTerms});
```

And add query parameters that you expect:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('search', {
    url: '/?term',
...
```

Comment: so my query would go in my app.js file where ui-router is configured? How does that tie in with ng-submit=search()?

Comment: I've been doing a lot of reading on ui-router and it seems that using ui-sref on an <a> would be better suited for this use case instead of $state.go, would you agree? Any examples, suggestions, links?

Comment: @user3125823 using ui-sref instead of state.go is almost always better idea, because when you add ui-sref directive, it resolves url from target state and adds it to href attribute. It's better choice because for example when you click middle mouse button, it will open in new tab (won't work with state.go).